# Magento : Not able to set a custom template using an extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, custom-template

I am creating a custom module to set a custom template for

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/default.phtml
```

but I am not able to override it. I have tried using XML like below

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="Hemag_StockStatus::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: try [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93319/20064)

Comment: I have already tried that but not work

Answer (score 1):

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.default" template="SR_MagentoCommunity::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_option = $block->getOption() ?>
<div class="field">
    <label class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option->getTitle()) ?></span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sohal Rana Still not working :(

Comment: Not sure why not working for you, this is working code with M2.3

Comment: can you please send me your working extension? I am using 2.2.6 version

Comment: I have added this two file and working fine. Did you check with fresh Magento installation or check any other module already overwrite this or not?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it in fresh magento 2.3 and its not working there.

Comment: have you disabled cache as i tested the above answer and worked fine. your initial code has invalid name also have you checked your theme to see if  the template file for product.info.options still containers <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>

Comment: @DavaGordon I am not clear with invalid name. Can you please elaborate?